# Fixed Div is hidding Scroll bars

Tags: css, scrollbars

I have a bizzare issue, I have a DIV that scrolls inside my page... But within that div I have 'header' that is FIXED.... and because my layout is fluid (100%) wide,it is making the "FXED" div cover over the scrollbars of the div below....

What is the best way to fix this? I have attached a simple screenshot of what's going on... hope it helps. [image]

```
/* BLUE SECTION */    
.floatingHeaderBox {
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* RED BOX BELOW */
    .contentBoxRight{
position:absolute;
width:80%;
left:20%;
height:100%;
background-color:#FFF;
border-left:1px solid #CCC;
margin-left:-1px;
}

.contentBoxRight{ overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden; }
```

Comment: Could you also post relevant code?

Comment: Could you post the HTML and CSS for the relevant elements?

Comment: I have added the respective CSS

Comment: Wouldn't the best way to fix it be put all the contents in a the DIV that has the overflow:auto? You will have to supply the HTML so we can see the flow. We'll just be taking wild guesses up until then.

Comment: You should add a link to your page. Without one, this seems difficult to solve. With one, it should be fairly easy.

Comment: Yeah i wish i could it's behind password protection... will see if I can setup a test page...

Comment: If you manage to do that, notify me in a comment containing `@thirtydot`, so that I get a [comment notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: Even having the HTML that goes with your CSS would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/yuliantoadi/bXukG/1/

i don't have your html, so i made it by my self.

Answer (score -1):

If your floatingHeaderBox is inside your scroll box like this:

```
<div class="contentBoxRight">
    <div class="floatingHeaderBox">Hdr</div>
</div>
```

You can just add a negative left margin to account for scrollbar. since x-overflow is set to hidden, you will not be able to tell that it moved. Add padding or a sub container to get your desired space back on the left side.

```
.floatingHeaderBox {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left:-18px;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as it is set to 100% width, margin-left, Shifts the entire box to the left....

Comment: How do you know that the scrollbars at 18px wide on all current and future browsers? What about Apple based stuff which doesn't show scrollbars by default?